# Mismatched input ',' expecting ')'

Tags: python, pine-script, indicator

I'm running this code to add to the script I've been compiling now but I'm getting this error and I just can't figure out what's wrong with it:

line 1 :

> mismatched input ',' expecting ')'

```
SMI_Long_Exit = (cross(sig, erg) and (sig>erg) and sig>0 ? : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
SMI_Short_Exit = (cross(sig, erg) and (erg>sig) and erg<0 ? : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)

plotchar(SMI_Long_Exit, color = color.green, location = location.abovebar, text="EXIT LONG", transp=0)
plotchar(SMI_Short_Exit, color = color.red, location = location.belowbar, text="EXIT SHORT", transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While declaring `SMI_Long_Exit`  and `SMI_Short_Exit` boolean variables you used `plot`'s function arguments (style, linewidth, color).

```
SMI_Long_Exit = cross(sig, erg) and (sig>erg) and sig>0
SMI_Short_Exit = cross(sig, erg) and (erg>sig) and erg<0

plotchar(SMI_Long_Exit, color=color.green, location=location.abovebar, text="EXIT LONG", transp=0)
plotchar(SMI_Short_Exit, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar, text="EXIT SHORT", transp=0)
```